# Clear a float not working properly

Tags: css, css-float

I understand to some degree how clearing a float works. But for this site I'm helping to work on I am unable to get the background of the `#PageContent` to clear and show the background for everything that is in it. What am i doing wrong?

[image]
http://murray-s-speed-and-custom.mybigcommerce.com/locations/

The inner guts are all floated left. So i would like the background of the id to extend to the bottom like it does on the about us page.

[image]
http://murray-s-speed-and-custom.mybigcommerce.com/about-us/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `overflow: auto;` to `#PageContent`. This way it would extend to the height of the content.

This is an alternative to adding, say a `<div style="clear: both;">` to the end of your content, below the floated elements.

Comment: You beat me to it by a second. :p

Comment: This is 100% true and that's why I find SO to be one of the best tools for a developer.

Comment: I agree. SO makes me happy to be a developer to know there are others I can turn to when my brain cant make since of whats happening. Thank you very much!